# Avoiding direct use of numbers

Tags: c#, class, numbers

I am working on a project involving images coming from a camera. I created a new `class` in which I defined a method that I can call to extract data from an image. Here is the code of the said `class` :

```
class DataFromBitmap
{
    static public Bitmap ImageToTreat; 
    double[] ValeurPixelsExperiment = new double[132];
    double[] ValeurPixelsReference = new double[132];
    double[] ValeurPixelsSumExperiment = new double[1024];
    double[] ValeurPixelsSumReference = new double[1024];
    int[] PixelColorCount = new int[256];
    int[] PixelColorCountReady = new int[256];

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves data from an input bitmap. Retrieved data : Ref and Exp pixel column mean values and count of each color level population. Output : double[1024] under ExpOutput() and RefOutput(), and int[256] under ColorCountOutput
    /// </summary>
    /// <param Bitmap to treat="pImageToTreat"></param>
    public DataFromBitmap(Bitmap pImageToTreat)
    {
        ImageToTreat = pImageToTreat;

        unsafe
        {
            int width = ImageToTreat.Width;
            int height = ImageToTreat.Height;
            int bytesPerPixel = 1;
            int maxPointerLength = width * height * bytesPerPixel;
            int stride = width * bytesPerPixel;
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bData = ImageToTreat.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, ImageToTreat.Width, ImageToTreat.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, ImageToTreat.PixelFormat);
            byte* scan0 = (byte*)bData.Scan0.ToPointer();
            byte B;
            for (int i = 0; i < ImageToTreat.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 157; j < 288; j++)
                {
                    int Pixel = bytesPerPixel * i + stride * j;
                    B = scan0[Pixel + 0];
                    ValeurPixelsExperiment[j - 157] = B;
                    PixelColorCount[B] += 1;
                }
                ValeurPixelsSumExperiment[i] = ValeurPixelsExperiment.Sum() / 131;

                for (int j = 484; j < 615; j++)
                {
                    int Pixel = bytesPerPixel * i + stride * j;
                    B = scan0[Pixel + 0];
                    ValeurPixelsReference[j - 484] = B;
                    PixelColorCount[B] += 1;
                }
                ValeurPixelsSumReference[i] = ValeurPixelsReference.Sum() / 131;
            }
            ImageToTreat.UnlockBits(bData);

            PixelColorCountReady = PixelColorCount.DeepClone();
        }
    }

    public double[] ExpOutput()
    {
        return ValeurPixelsSumExperiment;
    }

    public double[] RefOutput()
    {
        return ValeurPixelsSumReference;
    }

    public int[] ColorCountOutput()
    {
        return PixelColorCountReady;
    }
}
```

As you can see it is not very complicated. I have a problem, though. I would like to avoid directly using numbers (1024, 256...) when I create the arrays. I would prefer to do somthing like this :

```
double[] ValeurPixelsSumExperiment = new double[ImageToTreat.Width];
```

This would be much more convenient in case I want to change the size of the incoming image. The issue is that if I create those arrays in the DataFromBitmap method, they don't exist anymore for the Output methods, at the end.

Is there a convenient way to avoid using numbers in my case ? This particular case is just an exemple, I have several classes that I want to adapt.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using consts maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the instantiation of the arrays into the method `DataFromBitmap`. There you have access to the size of the bitmap.

So you would have something like:

```
class DataFromBitmap
{
    static public Bitmap ImageToTreat; 
    double[] ValeurPixelsExperiment;
    double[] ValeurPixelsReference;
    double[] ValeurPixelsSumExperiment;
    double[] ValeurPixelsSumReference;
    int[] PixelColorCount;
    int[] PixelColorCountReady;

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves data from an input bitmap. Retrieved data : Ref and Exp pixel column mean values and count of each color level population. Output : double[1024] under ExpOutput() and RefOutput(), and int[256] under ColorCountOutput
    /// </summary>
    /// <param Bitmap to treat="pImageToTreat"></param>
    public DataFromBitmap(Bitmap pImageToTreat)
    {
        ValeurPixelsSumExperiment = new double[pImageToTreat.Width];
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is perfect case, where you should define property with `set` method instead of simple field:

```
public static Bitmap ImageToTreat {
    set
    {
        ValeurPixelsExperiment = new double[value.Width];
        ImageToTreat = value;
    }
}
public double[] ValeurPixelsExperiment { get; private set; }
```

Note that, both have to either `static` or not!

You can apply same logic to the rest of your arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, and is sensible to use class level or static class constants for this type of things. It allows you to change them once in one place

[Constants (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants)

> Constants are immutable values which are known at compile time and do
>   not change for the life of the program. Constants are declared with
>   the const modifier. Only the C# built-in types (excluding
>   System.Object) may be declared as const. For a list of the built-in
>   types, see Built-In Types Table. User-defined types, including
>   classes, structs, and arrays, cannot be const. Use the readonly
>   modifier to create a class, struct, or array that is initialized one
>   time at runtime (for example in a constructor) and thereafter cannot
>   be changed.

You could also put them in a config file if you want to change them more often, i.e buffer size or something like that. however for what you describe constants seem a good fit

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create a class representing processing output, which will store all the arrays — they have high cohesion as far as are built by single piece of logic, thus it will be even more convenient to make this relation explicit.
Then instead of storing data in fields and having separate methods to access them, you just return result as an instance of this class from your method — you will be able to create arrays of proper size based on input in this case.

And as a side note, it's not a good idea to perform a complicated logic inside a constructor, it's not obvious from a client point of view. Usually it's expected that constructors perform only actions necessary for construction. With my proposal you should move logic into method instead; otherwise you won't be able to return anything.